# Is "margin: 0 auto" default for CSS divs?

Tags: css

I just took over a new project. The guy before me coded a lot of:

```
div#headertop {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Is this really needed or is this the default anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All current browsers have `margin: 0` as the default margin for `div` elements.

`margin: 0 auto` is not the same thing -- if the div has a fixed width, `margin: 0 auto` creates a `div` that is horizontally centered in its container.

Comment: Instead of setting `width`, one can make the `div` to **shrink** automatically depending on its contents. Use `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not default, unless he also set

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is needed to center `divs` on the page, provided there is also a `width` set.  The top is given no `margin` and the left and right are set automatically in relation to the page/containing element (based on the width of the `div`)

Answer (score 2):

`margin: 0 auto;` is a common practice for *horizontally* centering a particular element.

Comment: I would add that you can make it the default with a CSS reset, which is always a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

The default for a `div` is to be 100% wide, so centering it horizontally as a default does not make any sense.